# Google Google App Engine for static files in Joomla

Tags: php, google-app-engine, joomla

I want to use Google App Engine for the static data for my Joomla website. I want to host all the CSS and JS files on App Engine.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819346/how-to-host-static-html-files-on-appengine

Comment: Joomla makes things a bit different than just hosting static content, since presumably he'll need to get joomla to reference all of the CSS and js from the subdomain instead of wherever it likes to have this stuff by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joomla is written using PHP.

By default Google App Engine only supports applications written in Python, and in the future Java. See Google App Engine FAQ so PHP is not natively supported.

There is a way to run PHP on Google App Engine however by using a Java Virtual Machine named Quercus. Your biggest issue will be that it will require large amounts of modification to Joomla's source code with the change to using GQL instead of SQL.

Source: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/92-Running-PHP-on-Google-App-Engine.html

Are you looking for ways to easily scale your Joomla installation?

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine now supports PHP. Hence, you can run Joomla!.

See this [link](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/333055646).