# What's the best way to host some html & css onto Googles Servers?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

We have a simple html site with some css and javascript. 
Would like to host in on Googles servers.

Should we choose App Engine or start a web server using Compute Enginge?

If we choose App Enginge, we have to choose a language java, go, php etc. None of those suits us, we just have some html files.

Should we go with a server in Compute Enginge?

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Storage is better suited to this use, you can configure a bucket to serve a static web site, see https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

Comment: If you use app Engine with Google cloudstorage you have 5 GB of FREE quota, when you use the default bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Engine for this. You don't really need to use a programming language if you only want to serve static files. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/819360/556495

If you don't have too much traffic, App Engine will be free.